# Break the path to a file to use in columns of a SQLite database using Python?

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a list of paths to files in the following format.

```
/media/odroid/pen/lol.mp3 (*)
/media/odroid/pen/rev1/lol2.mp3 (**)
```

My goal is to create a SQLite DB with 6 columns (dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4,dir5,name) and put those file paths in it, so (*) and (**) will look like(sorry for poor graphic representation):

```
dir1 | dir2 | dir3 | dir4 | dir5 | name
-------------------------------------------
none | none | media|odroid| pen  | lol.mp3
none |media |odroid| pen  | rev1 | lol2.mp3
```

I'm currently using `str.split('/')` but it's complicated to deal with because it requires different treatment for lenghts. I see people using regular expressions, but I'm not sure how to do it(not even alone), and insert it at the database at the same time. Can someone provide me a guide or sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression is an option, but why don't you use `split` ?
Keep it simple :

```
path = "/media/odroid/pen/lol.mp3"
cols = path[1:].split("/")
for i in range(6-len(cols)):
  cols.insert(0, "none")

# => ['none', 'none', 'media', 'odroid', 'pen', 'lol.mp3']
```

Or using a function

```
def getColsForPath(path):
  cols = path[1:].split("/")
  for i in range(6-len(cols)):
    cols.insert(0, "none")
  return cols


print(getColsForPath("/media/odroid/pen/lol.mp3"))
print(getColsForPath("/media/odroid/pen/rev1/lol2.mp3"))
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/HOD2/1)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: Added a function

Answer (score 1):

try to use this regular expression:

```
/\/?([\w\d]+)??\/?([\w\d]+)??\/?([\w\d]+)??\/?([\w\d]+)??\/?([\w\d]+)??\/([\w\d\.]+)$/
```

You have to read paths one by one
You will have 6 groups with results (maybe 7, one additional with whole string). Each group, except the latest, is "lazy", it means that groups will fill from the end of string.